# How to call function CreateProcess in Delphi Prism?

Tags: delphi, dll, createprocess, delphi-prism, oxygene

I wrote

```
function CreateProcess(
            lpApplicationName:String;
            lpCommandLine:String;
            lpProcessAttributes:IntPtr;
            lpThreadAttributes:IntPtr;
            bInheritHandles:Boolean;
            dwCreationFlags:Int32;
            lpEnvironment:IntPtr;
            lpCurrentDirectory:IntPtr;
            lpStartupInfo:STARTUPINFO;
            lpProcessInformation:ProcessInfo):Boolean;
         external 'kernel32.dll';
```

but VStudio said "Semicolon" expected - after external and " "end" expected" after 'kernel32.dll';
Can you help me to load and call a function please?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the .NET Process Class .. it does not make a lot of sense to use interop in this case since you are already using Delphi Prism..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Comment: +1; the whole point about .NET is not about learning a language to program it, but to learn what is in the .NET Framework and make use of that. The .NET Framework is huge: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

Answer (score 3):

@Ilya, you are using a wrong syntax for call an external function. You need to use the `DllImport` keyword to get Windows interop working.

you must rewrite your function to

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
class function CreateProcess(
            lpApplicationName:String;
            lpCommandLine:String;
            lpProcessAttributes:IntPtr;
            lpThreadAttributes:IntPtr;
            bInheritHandles:Boolean;
            dwCreationFlags:Int32;
            lpEnvironment:IntPtr;
            lpCurrentDirectory:IntPtr;
            lpStartupInfo:STARTUPINFO;
            lpProcessInformation:ProcessInfo):Boolean; external;
```

check this working sample

```
namespace ConsoleApplication20;

interface
uses
    System.Diagnostics,
    System.Runtime.InteropServices;


type
PROCESS_INFORMATION =record
    hProcess    : IntPtr;
    hThread     : IntPtr;
    dwProcessId : UInt32;
    dwThreadId  : UInt32;
end;



STARTUPINFO =record
     cb       : UInt32;
    lpReserved: String;
    lpDesktop : String;
    lpTitle   : String;
    dwX       : UInt32;
    dwY       : UInt32;
    dwXSize   : UInt32;
    dYSize    : UInt32;
    dwXCountChars   : UInt32;
    dwYCountChars   : UInt32;
    dwFillAttribute : UInt32;
    dwFlags         : UInt32;
    wShowWindow : ShortInt;
    cbReserved2 : ShortInt;
    lpReserved2 : IntPtr;
    hStdInput   : IntPtr;
    hStdOutput  : IntPtr;
    hStdError   : IntPtr;
end;

  ConsoleApp = class
  private
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    class method CreateProcess( lpApplicationName: string;  lpCommandLine:string;  lpProcessAttributes:IntPtr; lpThreadAttributes:IntPtr;
                        bInheritHandles:Boolean;dwCreationFlags: UInt32;  lpEnvironment:IntPtr;
                        lpCurrentDirectory:string;var lpStartupInfo:STARTUPINFO;out lpProcessInformation:PROCESS_INFORMATION) : boolean; external;
  public
    class method Main;
  end;

implementation

class method ConsoleApp.Main;
var
lpStartupInfo        : STARTUPINFO;
lpProcessInformation : PROCESS_INFORMATION;
begin
        lpStartupInfo := new STARTUPINFO();
        lpProcessInformation := new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        Console.WriteLine('Creating Process');
        CreateProcess('C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe', nil, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, nil, var lpStartupInfo, out lpProcessInformation);
        Console.ReadLine();
end;

end.
```

Check theses link for mmore info

- [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- [A Closer Look at Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719485%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)