# How to import DLL in delphi-prism?

Tags: .net, dllimport, delphi-prism, oxygene

I am trying to import dll in my delphi-prism program and never done it before. So, after finding some answer online, I put something together as follows but doesn't work.

```
  MyUtils = public static class
  private
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Auto)]
    method timeBeginPeriod(period:Integer):Integer; external;
  protected
  public
    constructor;
  end;
```

Here is how I use it:

```
var tt := new MyUtils;
tt.timeBeginPeriod(1);
```

When I run my program, I keep getting the following errors.

- **"MyUtils" does not provide an accessible constructor.**
- **"System.Object" does not contain a definition for "timeBeginPeriod" in expression
  "tt.timeBeginPeriod."**

What am I doing wrong? How do you import dll in delphi-prism?

I followed this stackoverflow question - [Delphi Prism getting Unknown Identifier "DllImport" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741245/delphi-prism-getting-unknown-identifier-dllimport-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.

You don't need the constructor, so you can remove it:

```
MyUtils = public static class
private
  [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Auto)]
  method timeBeginPeriod(period:Integer):Integer; external;
protected
public
end;
```

If you're calling the `timeBeginPeriod` function from outside the unit where it's declared, you need to change it's visibility to `public`.

You also don't need to create an instance to call the function:

```
MyUtils.timeBeginPeriod(1);
```

I tested this with an app that declared and used `SendMessage` instead, so I could easily check to make sure it actually worked (I sent an `EM_SETTEXT` message to an Edit control on the same form).

Answer (score 1):

```
  MyUtils = public static class
  public
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Auto)]
    class method timeBeginPeriod(period:Integer):Integer; external;
  end;


MyUtils.timeBeginPeriod(1);
```

Comment: Ck. Thank you. I did change exactly as you have in your answer and it works. Now, I do have a question. Can I take this program and run it under mono on Linux along with the winmm.dll? Will it work as expected?